# Django upgrade from 1.7 to 1.8: Need variable from contextprocessor in view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.8

A number of variables must be determined during each page hit but used in various places in my project, not just templates but also in views. So far, I've been using a context processor (called 'globals') to achieve this result. Please note that in the context processor I'm doing actual computations and database calls, so I don't just need a settings variable.

Since upgrading from Django 1.7 to 1.8, the variables returned by the context processor still show up in the templates, which is good, but they no longer show up in the views, at least nowhere I can find them.

In my contextprocessor, I have the following code:

```
def globals(request):

    # NOTE: We DON'T simply need a variable from settings - in reality this is computed
    if_this_is_true_then_we_alter_text = True

    ctx = {
        'var_from_contextprocessor': if_this_is_true_then_we_alter_text,
    }

    return ctx
```

Then, in my view, I have:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render

def show_globals(request):
    ctx = RequestContext(request)
    ctx['var_from_view'] = 'YES, we found it!' if ctx.has_key('var_from_contextprocessor') else 'NO, it ain\'t there!'
    return render(request, 'show_globals.html', context_instance=ctx)
```

My template, `show_globals.html` is as follows:

```
var_from_view: {{ var_from_view }}
var_from_contextprocessor: {{ var_from_contextprocessor }}
```

When running Django 1.7, the output in the template from the view will be "YES, we found it!". However, once I've upgraded to 1.8, the variable returned by the context processor appears to be available to the view, and so the text changed to "NO, it ain't there!". In both cases, `var_from_contextprocessor` is however duly displayed in the template itself.

Is there still a way to retrieve variables from context processors in individual views? If not, any suggestions on how to achieve the same results without the use of a context processor?

Note that the basic problem I'm trying to solve is simply having variables calculated on the fly during each page hit, which are then available to both views and templates. I don't really care whether this is done by using a context processor or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered a solution that helps, at least in my case.

So the desired result is having code, which is run at every page load, with results available both in all views and all templates.

A technical reasons for why this stopped working with a simple contextprocessor between Django versions 1.7 an 1.8 are quite well explained in a different answer by Daniel Roseman, so I won't go into them here.

Long story short, the trick is to use a *middleware* instead of a *contextprocessor*, but then have the *contextprocessor* inherit the variables from the *middleware*.

Considering the code in the original question, compare with the new code:

Contextprocessor:

```
def globals(request):

    ctx = request.extravars # See example.middleware.ExtraVarsMiddleware

    return ctx
```

Middleware:

```
class ExtraVarsMiddleware():
    # For handing certain variables over to the context processor for global display.
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        # NOTE: We DON'T simply need a variable from settings
        if_this_is_true_then_we_alter_text = True

        request.extravars = {
            'var_from_contextprocessor': if_this_is_true_then_we_alter_text,
        }
```

The "global" variables are hung on to the request object in an arbitrarily named dictionary called *extravars*. Note that while our "global" variable entry is still called `var_from_contextprocessor`, it's a misnomer at this point since it's from the middleware, no longer the contextprocessor.

In order to activate this middleware, settings must be altered to include it, like so (defaults included):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'example.middleware.ExtraVarsMiddleware',
)
```

The templates then have access to variables as previously, since the context processor has added the entirety of `request.extravars` to its resulting context, which is then returned as per the code above.

Then, to access the variables in the view, we need a slight change from before:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def show_globals(request):
    ctx = request.extravars
    ctx['var_from_view'] = 'YES, we found it!' if ctx.has_key('var_from_contextprocessor') else 'NO, it ain\'t there!'
    return render(request, 'show_globals.html', context=ctx)
```

I've changed this code as little as possible to demonstrate the minimum changes needed. Only two things have changed, one is how the `ctx` dictionary is acquired, this time without using `RequestContext`. The second change is that we no longer pass `context_instance` to the `render` function, but simply `context`.

For clarification, the corresponding file names in my example setup are:

```
example/contextprocessors.py
example/middleware.py
example/views.py
settings.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing that changed between 1.7 and 1.8 was the introduction of different template backends, to allow first-class support for eg Jinja2. What this means is that context processors have moved from being a top-level setting to one associated with a particular template backend; for example, the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting is deprecated, although still supported for now.

The upshot of this is that a RequestContext is not associated with any particular set of context processors until it is associated with an actual template. By default, this happens when you call the template's `render` method (which itself is called by the standalone `render` shortcut you use above).

However, you could do this yourself, by calling `bind_template` explicitly and doing the rendering yourself in the view:

```
from django.template import loader

ctx = RequestContext(request)
tpl = loader.get_template('show_globals.html')
with ctx.bind_template(tpl.template):
    ctx['var_from_view'] = 'YES, we found it!' if ctx.has_key('var_from_contextprocessor') else 'NO, it ain\'t there!'
    return HttpResponse(template.render(ctx))
```

I must say though, this whole thing strikes me as being a misuse of context processors, which are called *template* context processors for a reason. You should look into reworking your code so that you don't need this access in the view - perhaps do it in a template tag?

Comment: Thank you for the information! You've clarified the reasons behind this. :) I'm not too sure about what exactly counts as mis-use, but my precise problem is that I need things both in view functions and in templates, but these are variables that I use on every page and so I find quite icky doing something in each view function to accomplish this. In general, I don't like repetitions being required for writing another view function.

I have however discovered how to achieve the desired result and will post it in another response for others. :) Long story short, use middleware instead.